# How to add continuously some Minutes to the time string and generate new time

Tags: javascript, time

i have a start Time and end time in string. i have split start time (time string format "05:30:00")

```
                var dateArray = data.start_time.split(":");                    
                var firstHour = dateArray[0];
                var firstMinutes = dateArray[1];
                var firstSec = dateArray[2];
```

now i want to Add 80 minutes to this time and want generate a new time (push in a array) , then i want to add it again n again to a end time limit how it is possible?

Comment: Convert all to minutes add and next get hours and minutes

Answer (score 0):

why not use check:

```
      var slog=80;
      var firstHour = dateArray[0];
      var firstMinutes = dateArray[1];
      var firstSec = dateArray[2];
        if(slog%60 != 0){// when slog is not fixed
                 firstHour=firstHour+slog/60;
                 firstMinutes=firstMinutes+slog%60;
            }else if(slog%60 == 0){
                      firstHour=firstHour+slog/60;
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the top of my head (not tested!):

```
yourTime = startTime;

 while(yourTime < endTime){
     yourTime.setMinutes(yourTime.getMinutes() + 80);
     dateArray.push(yourTime);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = new Date();
var theDate = d.getFullYear() + '-' + ( d.getMonth() + 1 ) + '-' + d.getDate();
var theTime = theDate + " 15:00:00";
var newTime = new Date( Date.parse( theTime ) + 80*60*1000 );
```